# Race Start Mode of Gran Turismo 5

Tags: gran-turismo-5

I do not like the way that races start by default, which is a rolling start. I would like to start the race with the cars stopped.

Can you change the game's race start type?

Comment: I suspect that rolling or normal starts are dependent on the race / tournament you are entering and therefore cannot be changed. If you are setting up your own races, it should be possible to specify the starting type. Unfortunately I can't tell you exactly how to do this, but hopefully someone else can.

Comment: The problem is that 99% of the game is like, as if it were in 4 where only a few races were so, it would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unfortunately cannot. The AI in GT is too cautious in its driving style, as you already might have noticed if you're a bit more aggressive before going into a corner.

The game uses the rolling start to give its AI a fair head start.

However, it is possible to pick the starting type in online hosted matches. Not in singleplayer.

IIRC, a 'regular' start only occurs in singleplayer for events where there's no AI present, like driving challenges.